# How can I group by date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

The following MySQL query get all weeks data by user for different dates:

```
SELECT user_id,
       CONCAT(follow_up_date, ' - ', follow_up_date + INTERVAL 6 day) AS week,
       GROUP_CONCAT(follow_up_date)
FROM   feedback_2
WHERE  follow_up_date > ''
GROUP  BY WEEK(follow_up_date),
          user_id
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
user_id |         week           | group_concat(follow_up_date)|
---------------------------------------------------------------
4        2012-08-28 - 2012-09-03 | 2012-08-28,2012-08-28,2012-08-29
14       2012-08-28 - 2012-09-03 | 2012-08-28
```

But my requirement is, how to separate different date for same user.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
user_id |         week           | group_concat(follow_up_date)|
---------------------------------------------------------------
4        2012-08-28 - 2012-09-03 | 2012-08-28,2012-08-28
4        2012-08-28 - 2012-09-03 | 2012-08-29
14       2012-08-28 - 2012-09-03 | 2012-08-28
```

Comment: try `GROUP BY follow_up_date, user_id`

Comment: 1. remove the user_id from the group by, so that same user_id's will be presented

Comment: hi, thank u for reply. Its working fine but it showing week field like this: 2012-08-29 - 2012-09-04 i.e different date.

Comment: we need weekly wise report for every month. i.e if the month is August, then the weeks starts from monday to saturday(06-11,13-18...) for every user.

Comment: what is the purpose of group_concat why do you need it? remove it and try GROUP BY week, user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  `user_id`, 
        CONCAT(`follow_up_date`, ' - ', `follow_up_date` + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS f_week, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`follow_up_date`) AS c_date
FROM feedback_2 
WHERE `follow_up_date` > ''
GROUP BY f_week, `user_id`
ORDER BY  `user_id`, f_week
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested , but you may try it:

```
SELECT user_id,
       _CONCAT(DATE_SUB(follow_up_date, INTERVAL _DAYOFWEEK(follow_up_date)-3
                                        day),
       ' - ', DATE_SUB(follow_up_date, INTERVAL _DAYOFWEEK(follow_up_date)-3 day
              )
       + INTERVAL 6 day) AS week,
       GROUP_CONCAT(follow_up_date)
FROM   feedback_2
WHERE  follow_up_date > ''
GROUP  BY WEEK(follow_up_date)
```

Please remove the `_` character when parts of the words in the expression start so that the query will be correct.

Comment: no it is not what i ment , it doesn't give me to write the whole sql statement , there some error in the blog , i will try to edit it in some way

Comment: but it is giving error in sqlyog editor: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'. please help me.

Comment: @user655334 : i forgot a comma after the second expression , try again, remove the "_" before the some of the expression words start

Comment: sorry, michael.. it returns only one user data. But,one more user also had data in the same date.

Comment: please check my sample output.

Comment: @user655334: i don't have your data , and table description so i can't test any query, does it give the correct output for user 4?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16007/discussion-between-michael-and-user655334)

Comment: i got michael.. i removed the "week" in the group_by week(follow_up_date) and added "user_id" in the group by statement.  so the query looks like this: "group by follow_up_date,user_id"